# Accessing variable from an inner class - getting null pointer exception

Tags: java, inner-classes

i want to access the `arr` variable from inside the inner class method `MyMethod`. When i try to print it from there i end up getting a null pointer exception.

```
public class MyClass{
    String[] arr;
    MyClass my;

    public MyClass(){
      my = new MyClass();
    }

     public class MyInner {
        public void MyMethod() {
            // I need to access 'my.arr' from here how can i do it. 
         }

       }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
       String[] n={"ddd","f"};

       my.arr=n;
     }
}
```

Comment: You are creating an infinite initializing loop in the constructor. What do you basically want to do?

Comment: Move the `= new MyClass()` out: `MyClass my = new MyClass()`. and may be `static` -- because you want to access it in `main` method. But after all, what do you want to do from the beginning?

Comment: i want to access `arr` which is declared in the outterclass from the innerclass method `MyMethod()`. `arr` will be initialize in the `main()` method.

Comment: I mean, do you really want `my` in `MyClass`? Or you want it initialized in `main` method? It seems you are accessing `my.arr` in `main`, so you just remove `MyClass my;` and `my = new MyClass();` and you can access `arr` (not `my.arr`, just `arr`) in `myMethod()`. And add `MyClass my = new MyClass(); my.arr = n;` in `main()`.

Comment: I think you should look at the concept of Constructor BTW: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized it yet, so the reference is `null`. Initialize it in your constructor for example, and you will have access to the variable via your inner class.

```
public class MyClass {
    String[] arr;

    public MyClass (String[] a_arr) {
        arr = a_arr;
    }

    public class MyInner {
        public void MyMethod () {
            // I need to access 'my.arr' from here how can i do it. 
        }

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String[] n= {"ddd","f"};
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass (n);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i initialize it at the constructor ?

Comment: @sharonHwk I have edited my answer with an example based on the code you have provided. I've also corrected the problem noted by Peter Lawrey. His answer is also really good BTW.

Comment: You are correct but, i have to initialize arr in the main() method it self. how should i edit the code to do so ?

Comment: @sharonHwk You can pass it as a parameter to your constructor. I've updated the code example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use just `arr`.  However until you set it to something it will be `null`

BTW: Your `my = new MyClass()` will blow up as it will create objects until it stack overflows.

Comment: How can i use arr inside the main() method as it's static

Comment: You have to create an instance of MyClass.  This means fixing the constructor so it doesn't blow up.

Comment: Ok done. but then how am i going to access `arr` from MyMethod(). How and where should i initialize the `arr`. sorry but i am a beginner

Comment: The hardest thing to remember is to write code which as simply as possible solves a problem.  You don't appear to be solving a problem which leads me to suggest you not do any of it.  However if it is just an exercise you need to create an instance of the nested class and you can initialise arr when it declared.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters in your main method you never create an instance of your class.

Also, `MyClass` has a reference to a `MyClass` object.  In the constructor of `MyClass`, it initializes that reference by calling it's own constructor.  That's an endless loop.

Comment: How do i initialize it at the constructor ?

Comment: If i remove the  MyClass reference from the constructor then how am i going to access the array from the main method ?

Comment: In the main method:
MyClass object = new MyClass();
object.arr;

Answer (score 0):

Do the following. Your way of initialization is wrong.

```
public class MyClass{
    String[] arr;
    MyClass my;

    public MyClass(){
    }

     public class MyInner {
        public void MyMethod() {
            // I need to access 'my.arr' from here how can i do it. 
         }

       }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
       String[] n={"ddd","f"};
       MyClass my=new MyClass();
String[] b = new String[2];

System.arraycopy( n, 0, b, 0, n.length );
     }
}
```

In case of more than 2 strings, simply do String[] b = new String[n.length];

Comment: I can't have it as `new String[2];`, i might even have more than 2

Comment: can u explain `System.arraycopy( n, 0, b, 0, n.length );` and will now be able to access `arr` from `MyMethod()` ?

Comment: System.arraycopy just copies an array into another . So it copies n to b  with the size of n.

Comment: Can you also show me how am i going to acess `arr` from the `MyMethod()` ?